# How to add aria-hidden property to span on focus change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid, wai-aria

I have to change the span element aria-hidden value to "true" on focus change event. How can I do that?

Here is my span element declaration-

```
<span id="jawshide">#someText</span>
```

and here is javascript part-

```
document.getElementById('jawshide').innerHTML= "aria-hidden='true'";
```

What is the correct way to add this property?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this using `setAttribute`

```
document.getElementById('jawshide').setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
```

Answer (score 7):

Js:

```
document.getElementById('jawshide').setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true")
```

JQuery:

```
$('#jawshide').attr("aria-hidden", "true")
```

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery:

```
('#jawshide').attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
```